# can't ride snake around canvas border in JS snake game

Tags: javascript, html

I've been spending the last few minutes messing with the condition that stops the game once the snake hits the canvas wall. My original problem was that the snake would go 1 unit pass the border before the game would stop, this was an issue because you can't see the snake hit the wall. After messing  with the relational operators in the if condition I was able to make the game stop as soon as the snake hit the border. Now the game stops as soon as the snake enters that very last unit making it so the snake is unable to ride the very edge of the canvas. I know i can expand the length and height within the condition, but this just takes me back to my first problem. Any help would much appreciated:)

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//set canvas dimension equal to css dimension
canvas.width = 768;
canvas.height = 512;

//now put those dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create snake array
let snake = [{x: cvsW/2, y: cvsH/2}];

//delcare global variable to hold users direction
let direction;

//create food object
let food = {
 x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit,
 y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit
}

//read user's direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', changeDirection);

function changeDirection(e) {
 //set direction
 if (e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
 else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
 else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
 else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
}

function draw() {
 //refresh canvas
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
 //draw snake
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
  ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, unit, unit);
 }

 //grab head position
 let headX = snake[0].x;
 let headY = snake[0].y;

 //check if snake hit wall
 if(headX <= 0 || headY <= 0 || headX >= (cvsW-unit) || headY >= (cvsH-unit)) {
  clearInterval(runGame);
 }

 //posistion food on board
 ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, unit, unit);

 //send the snake in chosen direction
 if(direction == 'left') headX -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'up') headY -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'right') headX += unit;
 else if(direction == 'down') headY += unit;

 //create new head
 let newHead = {x: headX, y: headY}

 if(headX == food.x && headY == food.y) {
  //create new food position
   food = {
   x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit,
   y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit
  }
  
  //add 3 units to the snake
  snake.unshift(newHead);
  snake.unshift(newHead);
  snake.unshift(newHead);
 }
 else {
  //remove tail
  snake.pop();
 }

 //add head to snake
 snake.unshift(newHead);
}

//run game engine
let runGame = setInterval(draw, 70);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake Game</title>
 <style>
  #canvas {
   background-color: #000;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="250px" height="250px"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue, you're clearing the entire game interval when the snake collides with the edge of the screen. Instead, you should prevent the player from going past the screen by setting their current x-position to their past x-position when the collision is detected.

Also, I know this is about 4 years late but better late than never!

I hope this helps!